# How to write a bash script to test table of logins?

Tags: linux, bash, security, iteration, hashtable

I've participated in a hacking competition in my school. I came up with a solution but i didn't knew how to code it so here am I asking for your help.

The problem involved a security breach on a server. Files with gmail usernames:passw had been leaked and we, the infosec team, had to test which logins were compromised (if users hadn't changed their pw yet) to email them. So my idea was: first, cat all files using `cat * > merged-file`. Then, somehow create a mechanism to test each combination usr + pw on gmail putting a flag or creating another file with the successful ones.

Sorry for my bad english, i'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check username and password using `curl`

```
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | grep "<TITLE>"
```

it will return `<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>` if the combination is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is an information security question and the answer is cut and clear,

> ALL OF THE ACCOUNTS HAVE BEEN COMPROMISED
>   
>   Every user of the system should receive an email notifying them. Even if *you* think the account is okay - it may not be. Let the user know AS SOON AS POSSIBLE.

In addition, there should *never* be any plain text files with user names and passwords - a password should be known to the user only - the server should only ever see an encrypted / hashed version.

Also, that is going to be a nice way of getting your IP blacklisted from Google, is if you attempt several hundred logins from a single source within seconds of each other, and probably highly against their TOS too.

Comment: I understand what u mean but i think u didn't get what's the point of the exercise. Obviously in a real world scenario a company should alert all of its users but the prerogative to only alert those that haven't changed their passwords creates an extra layer of difficulty to the exercise. Also, the text file is actually product of an XSS invasion where we played the "hacker" persona breaching our own server. That was the exercise number 1. About the IP blacklist, a simple proxychain with rand agent & MAC addr could solve the problem if necessary but in our case, our file had only 30 usr:pw.